# AWS Beanstalk cli-tool configuration validation exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to deploy sample rails app to aws beanstalk following [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html) tutorial. However on `eb start` cli-tool fails with the following message:

```
Some of your option settings are ignored because they don't apply to your environment type.
ConfigurationValidationException. Configuration validation exception: Missing value for required parameter: AWSEBDBPassword
```

I'm on Ubuntu 13.04, Python 2.7, AWS Beanstalk CLI Tools version 2.5

Comment: I am using the same environment as you and I also have the same problem with EB-CLI today. Seems AWS has made some upgrades and changes to EB and my version of the EB-CLI no longer works. But everything seems to work using the AWS EB web console, so I guess we expect to see an EB-CLI update soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evidently 2.5 of the CLI broke it.  Try going back to 2.4:

```
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk/cli/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.4.0.zip
```

---

[Edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201746/change-an-answer-from-downgrade-to-update-to-version-x-of-tool#201746) by [Victor Bjelkholm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/360186/victor-bjelkholm):

> Update to the latest version (2.5.1) where this is fixed.

```
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk/cli/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.5.1.zip
```

Comment: I got frustrated with the CLI, and just wrote a gem to make it dramatically easier for rails apps.  See https://github.com/alienfast/elastic-beanstalk

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem. In my case I'm using Windows 7 64 Python 2.7 AWS CLI 2.5 trying to deploy a Django project.

Upon inspecting the `aws_credential_file` in `home_dir\.elasticbeanstalk`, I can confirmed that the RDS password is indeed stored there. So the problem must be with AWS CLI.

Looking at the [EB online console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/home), I saw that the application was created, but not the environment. So I go ahead and create the environment myself using the online console with the same parameters I used in the CLI. The environment was created just fine with the RDS instance and everything. I can indeed see the sample application.

Then I go back to my local command line and test with `eb status` and got the green, ready status. I can then use `git aws.push` without any problem and can continue the tutorial.

Hope this help.